# Why sin done by Indra is suffered by all Women?

Tags: indra, sin

As discussed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17616/were-women-cursed-with-menstruation), the sin of *Indra* is suffered by *women*. But, why the sin done by someone is suffered by someone else? What I know is, we suffer the result of sinful action so that we can realize the sin we have done and change our mentality. So, there is no point in making someone else(women) suffer for the mentality someone(Indra) had.

Can anyone please answer my query? Why **all** women are suffering this pain?

---

**Edit**: After reading the link [Can sin be transferred?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/can-sins-be-transferred) I have understood that sin can be taken if someone is **willing** to take sins done by others. And usually, great rishis and incarnations can do that. But, in this case, it seems like every soul using a woman body, irrespective of their **will**, has to take the suffering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can sins be transferred?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/can-sins-be-transferred)

Comment: They suffered because they have accepted some part of the sin. Are you asking how is accepting sins of others possible?

Comment: @sv. Thanks, in the answer to that question, it is written that sin can be transferred by great rishis. And someone who is at a higher level of their spiritual journey has to take the sin. Why every woman is suffering irrespective of their will?

Comment: @Rickross I understood the part that someone can take the sin of others using their will power. But it seems like women have no option other than accepting the suffering. It seems like forcefully given. "Women" is a community, so some of them may have denied taking the sin! Suppose, the souls, who were present at woman body at the time when Indra divided the sin, agreed to take the sin. But, the souls who have taken woman body after that may not agree to take the sin. Am I able to make you understood?

Comment: As per the story the women did not refuse to accept some portion of the sin. They did it wilfully @taritgoswami

Comment: @Rickross Ok, so, the story tales like "every soul, now and in future, who will take a body of a woman" will voluntarily suffer the sin. But, can we deny that souls who have done some specific action gets women the body and suffer the pain of menstruation? Can it happen that, all souls having women body did some similar bad actions which result in the suffering of menstruation? Please correct me.

Comment: And thus, adharma unfolded by sacrifice demanded of unborn souls

Comment: Did you mean to ask, Why sin done by Indra is suffered by **all** women? If yes, suggest you edit the title accordingly.

Comment: They didn't take sin alone, they also got pleasure (kama) in return for it. If *all* women are willing to give up that kama to get rid of the sin, they all are welcome to do so. In other words, before a soul is about to take birth as a woman (or rather, given a woman's body by Bhagavan), all these desires, tradeoffs & karma are considered -  @Rickross, sv, tarit

Comment: Yes I know that. It's mentioned in the answers found in the linked page in the question. So I assume op is already aware of it @ram

Comment: Its a fake story dont give much importance to it