# What consequences will a person face if he kills a Brahmin?

Tags: scripture, puranas, brahmins

What are the consequences if a person kills a Brahmin? What sort of difficulties the killer will have and what will be the after effect of Brahmin atma?

Comment: Similar question [http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11202/](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11202/)

Comment: There is no varna for Jeevatman, it is mukta/free from such boundations. There is nothing like Bramhin Atman. The jeevatman would continue to suffer in the samsara as long as it is destined to, which in turn is based on jeevatman's karma balance.

Comment: @Yogi--Brahmin birth is the last stage that God gives us. We have to utilise it properly by doing nama japa etc. God knows how to classify the atmas. Hence I put Brahmin atma. Albeit you are a better knowledgable person than me you can go thru various puranas and other scriptures in quest of the answer.