# Is Killing a woman by a man sin ? Is even hitting a woman sin?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, puranas, manu-smriti

Is killing a woman or hitting on a woman (by a man ) sin ? What does various scriptures say about this ?

I know killing in general is sin but there are various situation where killing is not sin.
Killing another warrior by a warrior after giving him proper calling for a fight is not sin.
Killing a criminal by giving him death sentence is also not sin. etc.
For ex- Krishna Killed Shishupal , but it was not sin. Ram Killed Bali but it was not sin . (Although Ram didn't give him proper calling for a fight but still it was not a big sin as Bali was a bad person )

Comment: Sorry , I didn't explain it in detail. Killing another warrior by a warrior after giving him proper calling for a fight is not sin. 
Killing a criminal by giving him death sentence is also not sin. 
There are various situation where killing is not sin.

Comment: how are warriors and criminals related to this ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Why are you without any reason making a issue out of non-issue. We all know that there are be million situations where killing is not sin like - Krishna killing Shisupal and various other people. Krishna may not have killed them had they been women.  
And there is a popular belief in society that beating a woman is sin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why killing someone, stealing and drinking, all are equated on a same level of offense?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45280/why-killing-someone-stealing-and-drinking-all-are-equated-on-a-same-level-of-o)

Comment: @compaq then you ask about killing.  Dont involve gender. Because we cannot let someone promote hate crime on this forum

Comment: This is a very good question @RakeshJoshi please do not lie about the law. Gender-based discrimination **is NOT classified as hate crime by modern feminist laws of any country in the world.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Killing any one is of course a sin unless it is in a war. You really want to know if women can be given capital punishment and whether a woman can be hit. The answer to both these questions is negative. Women cannot be hit and they cannot be given capital punishment.

> Pay respect to womanhood, as they are all born of the family of the
> Divine Mother. Punish them not in however mild a manner, whatever the
> transgression. Their excellences, not failings, are to be stressed.

**Kularnava Tantra, Worship, Readings by M.P. Pandit**

Another passage on women is given below.

> **Then again woman can commit no fault.** It is man only that commits
> faults. By perpetrating an act of adultery, the man only becomes
> stained with guilt. It has been said that the husband is the highest
> object with the wife and the highest deity with her. My mother gave up
> her sacred person to one that came to her in the form and guise of her
> husband.  **Women can commit no fault. It is man who becomes stained
> with fault. Indeed, in consequence of the natural weakness of the sex
> as displayed in every act, and their liability to solicitation, women
> cannot be regarded as offenders.**

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCLXVI**

There are some stray passages that suggest hitting a woman. However, they can not be accepted as scripture because they do not satisfy the test of reason. Even a Shruti passage is invalid if it does not satisfy the test of reason.

Bhishma said in Mahabharata:

> Even the words heard from an ignorant person, if in themselves they be
> fraught with sense, come to be regarded as pious and wise. In days of
> old, Usanas said unto the Daityas this truth, which should remove all
> doubts, **that scriptures are no scriptures if they cannot stand the
> test of reason.**

**Mahabharata Shanti Parva Section CXLII**

Only passages that speak of love, justice and fairness thus satisfying reason are to be accepted. Those that do not are to be discarded.

> The Smritis and the Puranas are productions of men of limited
> intelligence and are full of fallacies, errors, the feelings of class
> and malice. **Only parts of them breathing broadness of spirit and love
> are acceptable, the rest are to be rejected.** The Upanishads and the
> Gita are the true scriptures.

**The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda/Volume 6/Epistles - Second Series/CXXIV**

Comment: @R.Kaushik Be warned this attitude of being disrespectful will not be tolerated on this site.

Comment: @R.Kaushik Read this line: "Kularnava tantra is an anti-Vedic scripture not considered shruti by any Hindu". Is it ok to say that?  If you would have read Kaularnava which I highly doubt, you would notice that at many occasions it praises Vedas. Not only that the initiation process also includes vedic initiation first.